# SoapSerializationEnvelope org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG

Tags: android, ksoap2

I'm getting expected : START_TAG {http....}

I'm not able to figure out where I missed,

I'm using .Net webservice

Belew is my code & error -

```
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://product.a.b.com/";
// Add a special character other than ':'
private static String METHOD_NAME = "prod|getProductDetailByCommercialRef";
private static String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;
```

//below line is working file

```
private static String URL = "http://test.a.b.com/bsl-fo-service/ProductService?wsdl";

public String getSoapRequest(String refID)
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("CommercialRef = "+refID);
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject("", METHOD_NAME);
        request.addSoapObject(getScopeBean());
        request.addSoapObject(getLocaleBean());
        request.addProperty("commercialRef", refID);
        request.addProperty("rangeId", "");

        // Instantiating ExtendedSOAPEnvelope
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new ExtendedSOAPEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11, NAMESPACE);

        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        CustomHttpTransportSE ht = new CustomHttpTransportSE(URL);
        ht.debug = true;

        ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        System.out.println("Request ID   ::::: "+refID);


        **System.out.println("Request Dump ::::: " + ht.requestDump);
        System.out.println("Response Dump ::::: " + ht.responseDump);**

        return ht.responseDump;
        // final SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope
        // .getResponse();

        // envelope.getResponse();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

Using KsopaVer-12

Getting error -

```
07-16 14:33:04.870: W/System.err(19902): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException:     expected: START_TAG {http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}Envelope (position:START_TAG <    {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}soap:Envelope>@1:71 in      java.io.InputStreamReader@4328b7b0) 
07-16 14:33:04.870: W/System.err(19902):    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.require (KXmlParser.java:2056)
07-16 14:33:04.870: W/System.err(19902):    at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:128)
07-16 14:33:04.870: W/System.err(19902):    at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:118)
07-16 14:33:04.870: W/System.err(19902):    at  com.schneider.soaphelper.CustomHttpTransportSE.call(CustomHttpTransportSE.java:204)
07-16 14:33:04.870: W/System.err(19902):    at com.schneider.soaphelper.CustomHttpTransportSE.call(CustomHttpTransportSE.java:63)
07-16 14:33:04.870: W/System.err(19902):    at com.schneider.soaphelper.CustomHttpTransportSE.call(CustomHttpTransportSE.java:58)
07-16 14:33:04.870: W/System.err(19902):    at com.schneider.soaphelper.OPSSoapHelper.getSoapRequest(OPSSoapHelper.java:43)
07-16 14:33:04.870: W/System.err(19902):    at com.schneider.dialog.OPSCustomDialog$1SendOPSReqAsyncTask.doInBackground(OPSCustomDialog.java:93)
07-16 14:33:04.870: W/System.err(19902):    at com.schneider.dialog.OPSCustomDialog$1SendOPSReqAsyncTask.doInBackground(OPSCustomDialog.java:1)
07-16 14:33:04.870: W/System.err(19902):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-16 14:33:04.870: W/System.err(19902):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-16 14:33:04.870: W/System.err(19902):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-16 14:33:04.870: W/System.err(19902):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-16 14:33:04.870: W/System.err(19902):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-16 14:33:04.870: W/System.err(19902):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Send Request to server code is below -

```
private void sendOpsRequest()
{

    class SendOPSReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            OPSSoapHelper helper = new OPSSoapHelper();
            System.out.println("Request ID Before sending request - refID  ::::: "+refID);
            //refID = refID.replace("http:", "http://");
            String response = helper.getSoapRequest(refID);
            return response;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String soapResponse)
        {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (soapResponse != null)
            {
                InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(soapResponse.getBytes());

                OPSXmlParser opsXmlPullParser = new OPSXmlParser();
                try
                {
                    opsBean = opsXmlPullParser.parse(inputStream);

                    if (opsBean != null)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Size>>>>>>>>>>> " + opsBean.size());

                        String imagePath = Constants.catchStoragePath(mainContext) + "/" + refID + Constants.IMAGE_FORMAT;
                        // TODO
                        // Bitmap productBitmap = ((BaseActivty) mainContext).convertBitmap(imagePath);

                        // productImage.setImageBitmap(productBitmap);

                        listsFragment.mImageFetcherLarge.loadImage(imagePath, productImage);


                        // get the listview
                        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.opsList);

                        listAdapter = new OPSExpandableListAdapter(mainContext, opsBean);
                        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                        expListView.setGroupIndicator(null);
                        layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++)
                        {
                            expListView.expandGroup(i);
                        } 
                    }
                }
                catch (XmlPullParserException e)
                {
                    Log.e("XmlPullParserException- OPS Parsing", e.getMessage());
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    Log.e("IOException in closing stream - OPS Parsing", e.getMessage());
                }
                finally
                {
                    try
                    {
                        inputStream.close();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        Log.e("IOException in closing stream - OPS Parsing", e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                CustomDialogBox dialog = new CustomDialogBox(mainContext);
                dialog.setMessage(mainContext.getString(R.string.no_ops_response_received));
                // dialog.show();
            }
        }
    }

    SendOPSReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendOPSReqAsyncTask();
    if (WebserviceUtil.isNetworkAvailable(mainContext))
    {
        sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute();
    }
    else
    {
        if (customDialogBox == null)
        {
            customDialogBox = new CustomDialogBox(mainContext);
        }
        customDialogBox.setMessage(mainContext.getString(R.string.network_unavailable));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

07-16 14:33:04.870: W/System.err(19902): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException:     expected: START_TAG {http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}Envelope (position:START_TAG <    {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}soap:Envelope>@1:71 in      java.io.InputStreamReader@4328b7b0)

means that the XML-parser does not get SOAP back but something different (could be anything, html error page for instance).
In your case, I'd try to reproduce the issue with another soap client. For this, log/dump the request from your mentioned application and send it with another tool (soapUI or curl from commandline) and check what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new ExtendedSOAPEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11, NAMESPACE);
```

to

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new ExtendedSOAPEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12, NAMESPACE);
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same kind of exception in my project. What I had done was that I had not named the service method correctly like (ABC.asmx.asmx instead of ABC.asmx)
That solved my problem hope that this might help you.